# How do I get the third daily card from the Steam Monster game?

Tags: steam-monster-game

Per the [Steam monster minigame's FAQ](http://steamcommunity.com/minigame/#FAQ):

> If you’re Steam Level 8 and above, you’ll get a Summer Sale trading card at random intervals while playing, up to three per 24-hour period.

Today is the 7th day of the sale, and I've gotten 14 cards from the game - two each day, and always right when I load up the game for the first time that day. I've tried leaving the game actively running in the background all day, but I have never gotten a third card for playing the game. What do I need to do to get that third daily card to drop?

Comment: Good Question +1 to you.. I likewise just get two cards when I start the game up each day for the first time.

Comment: @James I had forgotten to put that in the question, but it's always right when I start up the game that I get the cards, too.

Comment: Some guy on reddit said that you get a cards for a) joining a game b) reaching level 10 c) switching to a friend's game. Haven't tested it though.

Comment: @lunboks I just tested joining a friend's game. No card still.

Answer (score 1):

1st card: for joining a game.
2nd card: if you joined a friend's game.
3rd card: actively be there when level 10 gets beaten.

[Source](http://steamtradingcards.wikia.com/wiki/Monster_Summer_Game#Card_Drops)

Comment: Do you have a source for that that you can link?

Comment: -1 Does not work. I just tried joining a friend's game and did not get my third card.

Comment: @RobWatts I think they may have changed it. One the first couple of days I got the second card soon after starting a new game. Now I get two cards immediately. Something might be broken or they just changed up the criterion like they did with the milestones.

Comment: @BenCraig I just tested it and I got 3 cards. But since you probably want a source: http://steamtradingcards.wikia.com/wiki/Monster_Summer_Game#Card_Drops